# jquery plugin - 1 config setting get value from another config setting

Tags: javascript, jquery

When creating a plugin in jquery, i am creating my configurable settings like this:

```
var settings = $.extend( {
    'setting_one'  : 'setting_one_value',
    'setting_two'  : 'setting_two_value'
}, options)
```

What i would like to do is create another setting which depends on the value of either setting_one or setting_two.

For example:

```
var settings = $.extend( {
    'setting_one'    : 'setting_one_value',
    'setting_two'    : 'setting_two_value',
    'setting_three'  : setting_one + setting_two,
}, options)
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Why don't you compute that value when applying the settings?

Comment: Can you elborate on that, im not sure what you mean?

Comment: Just as in the answer of @AndreasAL. Maybe with an additional check "if not overwritten from options".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ops = (function (){
  var one, two, three
  one = 'foo'
  two = 'baz'
  three = one + ' ' + two
  return {
    one: one,
    two: two,
    three: three
  }
}())

var o = $.extend(ops, options)
```

Comment: You cannot do this. `ops` will first be defined when you end the object `}`

Comment: You were right. I edited now it should work with a self-executing function.

Comment: This just seams stupid to me. Then you can say: `ops = {}`, `ops.one = 'foo'`, `ops.two = 'baz'`, `ops.three = ops.one + ' ' + ops.two`

Comment: I don't think is that stupid, it might be potentially more code, but to my eyes it is more readable to have it all enclosed in `ops`, and it works better with my "code flow". I use this technique all the time. Take a look at the code of [this project I maintain](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms/tree/master/js) and you'll see this everywhere, it just keeps it tight and easy to follow IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you can archive this is by settings three after:

```
var defaults = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2
};
var options = {
  one: 2,
  two: 4
};

var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

settings.three = settings.one + settings.two;
```

Thats the only way to asure that you get the correct data to three, eq if options dosn't have the property `two`:

```
var options = {
  one: 2
}
```

`settings.three` will be `4`